# Python: How do I remove the input character length limit?

Tags: python-3.x

Recently, while trying to input a 5944 characters long string to my Python program, I noticed that only 4095 characters were being stored in the variable:

```py
# file.py
var = input("Enter: ") # Input 4095+ characters long string.
print(len(var)) # Outputs 4095.
```

I tried doing the same in REPL and surprisingly, all the characters were stored in the variable!

```py
>>> var = input("Enter: ") # Input 4095+ characters long string.
Enter: <6016 characters long string>
>>> len(var)
6016
```

So I have two questions:

- Why is there a limit of 4095 input characters when taking it from a `.py` file but not in REPL?
- Is there a way I can remove the input limit in the file as well?

I do plan on implementing a feature to let the user pass a file with their input instead, but I am curious about the answers to the above questions.

Comment: I tested both, executing via a file and in an interactive console, and cannot reproduce your problem with a string containing only numbers (10k+ characters). Could it be that your string has unicode characters, separators or some weird stuff inside, and if so can you identify them?

Comment: @mnikley, interesting. The input I provided was a comma separated string of names: `name1, name2, name3, ....`.

Comment: hmm, tried according to your format with a string of 15k characters, still works. What is the cut-off character at position 4095 in your string? (Include some surrounding characters aswell please)

Comment: `...na-mang|aka...` the `|` is where the text gets cut off (note: `|` is not a part of the input), at exactly the 4095th character. Which operating system are you on? This might be a Linux or bash/zsh thing, since I'm on Linux.